# Storyboard UITextview and buttons inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextview

I am trying to design a license page in which the user must accept a license before moving forward.  I want the user to scroll the contents of the text and at the bottom of the text to see a 'exit', and 'agree' button.  IE I do not even want the user to see the buttons until the have scrolled to the bottom.

I have a scrollview, that contains a textview and  the two buttons in my storyboard.  However I cannot get the textview and buttons to be scrollable together.  Has anyone setup something like this before in storyboarding?

EDIT:

Attaching a screen shot to show what I am trying to do in storyboard

[image]

Again I want to scroll the entire text view (if it fills the page) and have the buttons at the bottom of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIScrollView` than put `UITextView` inside of it. At the bottom of `UIScrollView` put the buttons.